# Numerically solving a second order ODE of two related functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

$$w''(s)+s''(x)w'(s)-\frac{w(s)}{s'(x)^2}=g(s)$$

So, I have this formula.  It's pretty ugly, and I'm looking to numerically solve it.  I know exactly what s(x) is, and want to solve for w(s).

My question is, what do I need to do to g(s) over there?  Should I change it to a a function such that $f(x) = g(s)$ which makes it consistent to the coefficient functions, or is there something else I need to do?  I particularly need $w$ to remain in terms of $s$, so I need to make sure that isn't messed with.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to write to write your whole equation in terms of $x$. Thus, $g(s)$ becomes $g(s(x))$, as you already suspected. Furthermore, you need to apply the chain rule to write the derivatives of $w$ in terms of $x$, e.g., $w'(s)$ becomes
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}x}
= \frac{\partial w}{\partial s} \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}
\,.
$$
After you made all these substitutions, you can solve the equation using your favorite numerical method; you obtain a solution $w(x)$. To get $w(s)$ you have to use the relation that $s = s(x)$. Hence, $x = s^{-1}(s)$, where $s^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $s$. Thus,
$$
w(s) = w(s^{-1}(x))
\,,
$$
which gives you the desired solution.